# Как следует переводить wiki excerpt?

Tags: поддержка, статус-завершено, локализация, термины

Как следует переводить wiki excerpt? В первоночальном переводе можно столкнуться с такими переводами:

- выдержка;
- отрывок;
- краткое описание.

Comment: если это (под-)заголовок, возможно, подойдёт просто: «кратко»

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Выбранный вариант*.

"краткое описание".

---

*Отклоненные варианты*.

- выдержка.
- отрывок.

Comment: Какую силу имеют "Остальные варианты"? Их тоже можно использовать в зависимости от контекста?

Comment: @alexolut Остальные варианты – это те варианты, которые были предложены сообществом, то есть из которых был выбор. Использовать следует только выбранный.

Comment: тогда не вижу смысла держать их в теле ответа.

Comment: @alexolut Они остались для общей справки. Решения по самым первым переводам принимались на «старой Мете», которая была закрыта. Публикуя результаты на этом сайте, хотелось бы сохранить историю, а не только финальные решения.

Comment: По идее историю видно через список ревизий, т.е. она не потеряется. Однако вот эти "остальные варианты" меня немного смутили. Хотел как раз поправить "отрывок" на "краткое описание" и задумался.

Comment: @alexolut Ревизий нет! «Старая Мета» – это отдельный сайт, который был закрыт.

Comment: Постойте, но сейчас-то разговор мы на активной (новой) Мете ведем. Почему бы прямо сейчас не взять и не подредактировать вопрос, оставив только итоговый вариант?

Comment: @alexolut На мой взгляд, если мы удалим то, что задумывалось оставить для общей справки, общая справка пропадет и цель достигнута не будет. Никто не будет искать историю голосования в ревизиях основного ответа (как минимум, для меня, это выглядит неочевидным).

Comment: Мне просто непонятен смысл держать предложенные варианты помимо вопроса ещё и в **принятом** ответе. Даже и для общей справки (хотя, я честно говоря, не совсем понимаю, чем *общая* справка отличается от обычной справки). Альтернативный вариант - добавить новые ответы, параллельно с принятым. В таком случае их можно увидеть (хотя они и так есть в вопросе) без просмотра ревизий, и при этом они не будут находиться внутри принятого ответа.

Comment: @alexolut Зачастую предложенных вариантов нет в вопросе ([например](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/481/)).

Comment: возможно тогда есть смысл переименовать "Остальные варианты" на "Отвергнутые варианты" (сразу понятно, что их использовать нельзя). Если идея с разбитием ответа не подходит по какой-то причине.

Comment: @alexolut Возможно лучше «Отклоненные варианты»?

Comment: Да. Видимо о них я и думал, но предложит почему-то "отвергнутые" :)