# Стойкость и выдержка в кратком описании меток

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, предлагаемые-правки, описание-метки

На заре перевода обсуждался вопрос «[Как следует переводить wiki excerpt?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/455/181472)». Был выбран вариант:

- **краткое описание;**

и отвергнуты:

- выдержка,
- отрывок.

Однако, в данный момент на сайте присутствуют все варианты. Очевидно, нужно привести их к единому виду. Поскольку даже в рамках выбранного варианта можно по-разному формулировать предложения, предлагаю публиковать варианты перевода.

Вот список мест, где встречается этот термин (дополняйте по возможности):

1. При редактировании описания метки показывается справочный блок, в котором:

   > *Выдержка описания* метки — это краткое текстовое описание тематики...
2. На странице [правки, ожидающей проверки](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/86) есть ссылка с текстом «*Выдержка метки*», но ведет она на полное описание метки.
3. В истории правок и [истории предложений](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/181472/nick-volynkin?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) на странице пользователя — непереведенный текст:

   > ```
   > утверждённая правка на featured tag wiki  
   > утверждённая правка на featured tag wiki excerpt
   > ```
4. В нижней части страницы описания метки есть блок, содержащий все варианты:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: пришедшие в голову синонимы, в той или иной мере отражающие суть: «подсказка», «инструкция», «рецепт», «директива».

Comment: Спасибо за замечания! Поправил все, кроме, наверное, [пункта 3](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40266666?qt=%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D0%BD%D0%B0).