# Сломался перевод строк на странице метки

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, метки

1. На [странице любой метки](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/discussion)

   > подробнее…  **improve tag info**  лучшие участники  синонимы
2. У "improve tag info" нет всплывающей подсказки, а у остальных есть. [Впрочем, на en.so тоже нет подсказки, может это и не баг](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/302724/2790048).
3. На [странице информации по метке](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/discussion/info), в нижней части кнопка.

   <kbd>Edit tag info</kbd>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> improve tag info

**улучшить описание метки**

> Edit tag info

**Редактировать описание метки**

(раньше был именно этот вариант, [тут есть подтверждающий скриншот](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/947/181472))

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка связана с переездом дата-центра. На сколько мне известно, в ближайшее время "пропавшие" переводы должны вернуться на место без внешнего вмешательства.

Comment: Что-то не возвращаются они.

Comment: Обещают на первой неделе сентября исправить.

Comment: Вернулись когда-то, но там были не совсем корректные строки. Исправил.